# Dejar colores fijos en grafica pie de Google charts

Tags: google-chart-api

Cordial saludo.

En la actualidad en el sitio web que estoy construyendo, tengo una grafica pie de Google Charts que alimento de una base de datos de SQL Server y se me esta presentando la siguiente situacion:

la grafica debe mostrar los porcentajes de los siguientes estados:

- VENCIDA,
- RENOVAR,
- OK,
- CATEGORIA SIN REGISTRAR,
- CATEGORIA NO APLICA.

La base de datos entrega los datos ordenados de la Z a la A, así que los estados siempre se muestran en el orden mencionado anteriormente.

Teniendo ello presente, le definí un color a cada estado. La gráfica se puede filtrar por año, mes y obra; pero cuando por ejemplo pongo una obra en la que no tienen el estado VENCIDAD, el color de este estado pasa al estado RENOVAR y así con los demás estados.

Pude notar que Google Charts pie, le asigna un color a los índices de la lista, lo que quiere decir que el dato que aparezca de índice 0, siempre tendrá el color definido y lo mismo con el resto de colores, según el índice, tendrán el color asignado.

Mi deseo es que el estado VENCIDA, tenga siempre el color ROJO, RENOVAR el color NARAJANDO, OK el color VERDE, CATEGORIA SIN REGISTRAR el color AZUL y CATEGORIA NO APLICA el color MORADO.

Les comparto el código que estoy usando, el cual lo estoy implementado con C# en VISUAL STUDIO.

```
<%--componete 1: filtro año--%>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Seleccionar año: " AssociatedControlID="txAno" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="txAno" runat="server" DataTextField="Ano" DataValueField="Ano" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="txAno_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>


    <%--componete 2: filtro mes--%>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Seleccionar mes: " AssociatedControlID="txMes" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="txMes" runat="server" DataTextField="Mes" DataValueField="Mes" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="txMes_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>


    <%--componete 3: filtro obra--%>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Seleccionar obra: " AssociatedControlID="txObra" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="txObra" runat="server" DataTextField="Obras" DataValueField="Obras"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txObra_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>


    <%--componete 4: Grafica--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
         <div id="myChart" style="width:100%; max-width:600px; height:500px;"></div>

        <script>
            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= GetGrafica() %>);

                var options = {
                    title: 'ESTADOS LICENCIAS DE CONDUCCIÓN',
                    colors: ['#ff0000', '#ffa833', '#58d68d', '#5499c7', '#af7ac5']
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
```